# Symfony 2 Security Login, 3 Field login?

Tags: php, security, symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle

I'm currently building an application and I need a 3 field login.

- Company Name [field 1]
- User of The Company[field 2]
- Password [field 3]

What is the best way to do this in Symfony?

Maybe I should use FosUserBundle or just the standard security component of symfony2?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Tommie, Did you get this sorted? I have been trying to work it out for ages!